# Environment Properties Not Avaialble In Django ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set a few variable properties by going to the environment -> configuration -> Modify Software -> Environment properties.

When I SSH into the instance, activate the virtual environment and run python and check for the variable, it returns nothing.

This is what I type before I enter the python shell:

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
cd /opt/python/current/app/
python

>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('VARIABLE')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Amazon Linux 1**, the EB env variables are **stored** in `/opt/python/current/env` . Thus, to **source them** after you ssh into the instance you can do the following:

```
source /opt/python/current/env
```

Comment: it worked! You mentioned that I am using Amazon Linux 1 but on my dashboard it says Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.12

Comment: @Anatol `Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux` is amazon linux 1:-) `2.9.12` is eb platform version, not linux version.

Comment: Now I can access the variables but I get Permission Denied when I run the collectstatic command?  @Marcin

Comment: @Anatol Seems like a new issue. Maybe better to  make new question with relevant details and error messages.